# Que aparezca en el select el dato que tengo en data value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy teniendo un problema. Necesito que cuando en data-value del select aparezca con cualquiera de las distintas opciones (en este caso he mostrado Póliza Contratada), por defecto me aparezca ese select y no el "Seleccionar". El data-value lo informará una base de datos y esto será una pregunta de un formulario que necesito que venga por defecto contestada con lo que hay en data-value
No sé cómo hacerlo.... Si me pudieseis ayudar... gracias

```html
<p class="rojo planes"> 4. Estado del cierre</p>
                <br>

                <ul class="puntos-encuesta pregunta">
                <select class="algo-mas-cc-selector" id="fe684" name="P2_4"  data-value="Póliza Contratada">
                     <option value="Seleccionar">Seleccionar
                      </option>
                      <option value="Póliza contratada">Póliza contratada
                      </option>
                      <option value="Ilocalizable">Ilocalizable
                      </option>
                      <option value="No interesado">No interesado
                      </option>
                      <option value="No procede">No procede
                      </option>
                      <option value="Pendiente de respuesta">Pendiente de respuesta
                      </option>
                      <option value="Volver a llamar">Volver a llamar
                      </option>
                      <option value="Otras gestiones">Otras gestiones
                      </option>
                  </select>

                </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo único que tendrías que hacer es capturar el valor del atributo `data-value` para usarlo para darle valor al `<select>`.

También habría que controlar el que si el valor que tiene el atributo `data-value` no se encuentra entre los `<option>` del `<select>` seleccionar uno por defecto para que no se quede ninguno seleccionado.

```js
$(function () {
  seleccionar_option ();
});

function seleccionar_option () {
  let valor = $('#fe684').data('value');
  
  $('#fe684').val(valor);
  
  if ($('#fe684').val() === null) {
    $('#fe684').val('Seleccionar');
  }
  
  return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="algo-mas-cc-selector" id="fe684" name="P2_4"  data-value="Póliza contratada">
   <option value="Seleccionar">Seleccionar
    </option>
    <option value="Póliza contratada">Póliza contratada
    </option>
    <option value="Ilocalizable">Ilocalizable
    </option>
    <option value="No interesado">No interesado
    </option>
    <option value="No procede">No procede
    </option>
    <option value="Pendiente de respuesta">Pendiente de respuesta
    </option>
    <option value="Volver a llamar">Volver a llamar
    </option>
    <option value="Otras gestiones">Otras gestiones
    </option>
</select>
```

No obstante te recomiendo no tener ese tipo de `value` en tus `<option>`. Espacios, acentos y carácteres especiales no son amigos del programador y se deberían evitar. En estos casos lo que se suele hacer es tener `value` numéricos para los `<select>` y e interpretarlos luego en tu código como necesites.

**Ejemplo:**

```
<select class="algo-mas-cc-selector" id="fe684" name="P2_4"  data-value="1">
   <option value="-1">Seleccionar
    </option>
    <option value="1">Póliza contratada
    </option>
    <option value="2">Ilocalizable
    </option>
    <option value="3">No interesado
    </option>
    <option value="4">No procede
    </option>
    <option value="5">Pendiente de respuesta
    </option>
    <option value="6">Volver a llamar
    </option>
    <option value="7">Otras gestiones
    </option>
</select>
```